# Stringoutofboundexception for string

Tags: java

```java
String s;
String x; 
x = scan.nextLine(); 

try{
    s=x.charAt(0);

}catch(StringIndexOutofBoundsException siobe)
```

Can someone help me here i know scan.nextline() gives a character however i am required to use string else my entire program will not work. So is there anyway to handle an exception in such a way that i am able to manage to keep string after scan.nextline().

```java
while (scan.hasNext()) 
{
    String x; 
    x = scan.nextLine(); 

    try{
        s=x.substring(0,1);
    }
    catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException siobe)
    {
        System.out.println("invalid input");
    }
```

Comment: scan.nextLine returns a String, not a character.  So not sure what your question is now.

Comment: The presence of `StringIndexOutofBoundsException` in your code makes me think you've incorrectly tagged your post `C++` instead of `Java`.

Comment: then how come eclipse is telling me to convert s to char ?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious yes it is a java question i have tagged it to java now. Why am i getting negative flags ?

Comment: You didn't test x to see if you actually read anything and have a character 0 to read. Dude, you really have to start checking your input before using it.

Comment: @user4581301 i forgot to mention in question that i am getting my strings from a text file.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious i am not able to ask questions can u please lift the flags off because it was a honest mistake

Comment: @Imcphers I a not able to ask questions in forums and it says i have to wait till 7 days. If u flagged my question can u please lift of the flag...i need help

Comment: @JonAbraham If you're getting a message saying that you have to wait 7 days before posting another question, that means you've run afoul of the throttling system that's currently in place (and no, none of the people who've downvoted can reverse the throttle). The basic idea is that if your questions aren't doing so well, you should be taking the time to go back over what you've already posted, try to learn why they weren't received well, and to use what you've learned to both improve the questions that you've already written and any questions you may write later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i know scan.nextline() gives a character

No, it gives a string.

> So is there anyway to handle an exception in such a way that i am able to manage to keep string after scan.nextline().

The real problem is that you are not handling the case where `nextLine()` returns an **empty** string.  You *cannot* retrieve characters from an empty string - there is no characters present!

```
String x = scan.nextLine(); 
if (!x.isEmpty()) { // <-- add this
    char ch = x.charAt(0);
    // use ch as needed...
}
else {
    // do something else ...
}
```

If you must have the `char` as a `string`, you can do this:

```
char ch = x.charAt(0);
string s = String.valueOf(ch);
```

Or this:

```
string s = x.substring(0, 1);
```

**Update:**

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    String x = scan.nextLine();
    String s;
    if (!x.isEmpty()) { // <-- here
        s = x.substring(0,1);
    } else {
        s = "";
    }
    // use s as needed...
}
```

Comment: okay folks to clear your confusion. There is a textfile where i am getting all of my strings.

Comment: while (scan.hasNext()) 
 {
        String x; 
     x = scan.nextLine(); 
     
     try{
      s=x.substring(0,1);
     
     }catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException siobe)
     {
      System.out.println("invalid input");
     }
     s=x;

Comment: @JonAbraham: You are STILL not checking if `x` is empty before accessing its characters. [`substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) can throw that exception: "*Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or **endIndex is larger than the length of this String object**, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.*"  When `x` is empty, `endIndex=1` is larger than `x.length()` which is 0. Please look more carefully at the code in my answer.

Comment: perhaps i should have mention this in the beginning of question. I am not getting IndexOutOfBoundsException error in short strings but only in long strings. I believe it has to something to do with length of the string itself. I already implemented the code that you suggested me but i am still getting that error. I am easily able to read strings such as (x,y,z , a+b, a=b+c,) however when i put strings such as (programming, or student) it throws me an error.

Comment: Please post a new question showing the ACTUAL code you are using (or at least an *accurate* [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of it), and explain where in the code the error is happening.